# Comparar dos arreglos y ejecutar según sea necesario

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes tengo una especie de carrito donde puedo ir agregando productos, tengo la opción de guardarlo y cuando lo guardo se guarda en mi BD.

Realmente lo que estoy haciendo es: He creado una tpv para un restaurante, entonces una vez guardo un producto llega los pedidos a cocina con el número de ticket, en este caso solo preparan los pedidos que son necesario que se hacen en cocina. Entonces una vez preparan un producto le dan a un botón y actualiza la BD con el ticket el producto_id y cambia esa columna de preparado de 0 a 1.

Entonces luego pueden recuperar ticket y añadir un producto nuevo, pero claro antes eliminaba todo el ticket y lo volvia a generar pero si habia ya un producto en `preparado` = 1 me lo devolvia a un 0. Entonces busque como hacer que eso no pasara, abajo explico como hago.

**Mi tabla orders**

| id | ticket | preparado | producto_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021316 | 0 | 59 |
| 2 | 2021316 | 0 | 75 |
| 3 | 2021316 | 1 | 25 |

**Así ejecuto ahora para no eliminar todo el pedido y añadirlo de nuevo**

```
        $elticket= $pedido->ticket;

        //PRIMERO EXTRAEMOS LOS DATOS ACTUALES DE LA BD EN ARRAY//
        $opciones_actuales=Order::where('ticket', $request->elTicket)->get()->pluck('producto_id')->toArray(); 
        //ESTAS SON LOS PRODUCTO_ID QUE VIENEN EN TU REQUEST//
        $opciones = [];
        foreach($request->carrito as $item){
            $opciones[]=$item['Producto_id'];       
        }
        //CON EL METODO ARRAY DIFF Compara array1 con uno o más arrays y devuelve los valores de array1 que no estén presentes en ninguno de los otros arrays, de esta forma podras saber cuales fueron las opciones eliminadas
        if($opciones)
        $opciones_eliminadas=array_diff($opciones_actuales,$opciones);

        //LUEGO RECORRES LOS ELIMINADOS Y LOS BORRAS DE TU BD
        if($opciones_eliminadas)
        {
            foreach ($opciones_eliminadas as $eliminados)
            {
                //dd($eliminados);
                $deleteProducto = Order::where('producto_id', $eliminados)->where('ticket', $pedido->ticket);
                $deleteProducto->delete();
            }
        }

        if($opciones)
        foreach ($request->carrito as $ind=> $item)
        {

          if(Order::where('ticket', $elticket)->where('producto_id', $item['Producto_id'])->exists())
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                //Guardo el producto nuevo
                $addOrder = new Order;
                $addOrder->ticket = $elticket;
                $addOrder->mesa_id = $request->zona_id;
                $addOrder->producto = $item['Name'];
                ........
            }
```

Cual es mi problema?, que si añado otro producto igual, por ejemplo tenia ya en la bd unos pops de queso y añado otros, al existir la `producto_id` ya no ejecuta la función, también hay que tener en cuenta que puedes recuperar el ticket y no añadir nada nuevo o eliminar, el de eliminar lo tengo pero si borro un producto que está dos veces me va eliminar los dos.

Se podría comparar las posiciones de los elementos?

Comment: Buen día, por qué no agregas una columna con un id interno del ticket para cada producto? De esa forma podrías agregar más de una vez el mismo producto y si requieres hacer cambios o eliminar un producto solo lo eliges a través del id interno del ticket. Es decir, podrías tener tus columnas id | ticket | preparado | producto_id | articulo_id. Donde articulo_id es el numero de productos dentro de un ticket y va de 1 a n